# What's a verb that means "to say something in a singing way"

Tags: dialogue, word-choice

Imagine a dentist telling a small child to "open wide." He might "sing" it rather than say it, maybe by drawing out "wide" into two syllables, the first having a higher pitch than the second. You probably know what I mean. Is there a good, single verb for this? I could just write "'Open wide,' he sang", but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lilting. "Open wide" he said, in a lilting voice.

Answer (score 2):

[**intone**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/intone) - to utter in a singing voice;  [to utter something in singing tones or in monotone](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intone)

> "Open wide," he **intoned**.

[Dictionary.com]
[Merriam-Webster.com]

Comment: Please quote the relevant definition and mention the source dictionary by name.

Comment: @NVZ - Isn't the link to the source definition adequate?

Comment: No, that's not enough. See also: [How to reference material written by others](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Comment: The linked dictionary page may list a million definitions for a word. Also the link might get broken sometime later. If we quote the relevant definition here, it will save us from these issues. :)

Comment: I think any child would be terrified by a dentist intoning 'open wide'.... The OED gives a slightly different def of 'usually to recite in monotone', and cites Johnson's definition of ‘to make a slow protracted noise’. It may be that the implications are different in US English, but in UK English a dentist intoning at you would not be encouraging or relaxing to most...

Comment: I do not completely understand why, in the definition, it gives both 'in singing tones' and 'in monotone', because to my mind they are different and, in fact, contradictory - nonetheless, that is the definition. I also thought of **lilted**, but that sounded completely wrong to me.

Comment: I ultimately went with "said". -.-

Comment: Good choice. In context, the word 'coaxed' might work, but that does not mean 'sing-song'.

Answer (score 0):

"Open wide" he crooned.
or ...
"Open wide" he soloed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: sing-song]

Sing songy voices would be monotone and dull.

I didn't know if you knew that, but, now you do.

Comment: Hm. I did not. Changed to "singing"

Comment: okay, I don't really know how to answer your question without shoving my novel down your throat. :{